# Tool to add a mouse pointer or cursor to an existing image or screenshot

Tags: screenshot, image-editing

Many years ago, I had a program that could take a screenshot, and from within the program, I could add mouse pointers (as many as I wanted) to me screenshot *after it was taken*.

I'm aware that there are many screen capture utilities that can include the mouse pointer or cursor in the screen shot.  I also know that, with enough know-how, almost any image editing program can add a pointer to an image or screenshot.  But what I am looking for is an *easy, simple, and quick* way to add a mouse pointer or cursor to an already existing image or screenshot.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps the program you used was [MWSnap](http://www.mirekw.com/winfreeware/mwsnap.html), (Windows app) a circa 2002 program that still runs on Windows 10, and has the ability to add various cursors and pointers to images.

For cross-platform, there's [Cursor that Screenshot](http://edbentley.github.io/cursor-that-screenshot/), a GitHub repository and website that allows you to upload an image and add a cursor to it using just your web browser.